# How to make a DialogFragment wrap its content and align a view to the bottom at the same time?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I would like to build a `DialogFragment` which contains a `ListView` and a bottom `View` (holding some buttons).

- The `ListView` can show a variable number of items and thus has a **variable height.**
- The bottom `View` has **fixed height**.

This is the Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

    <!-- Any kind of view. e.g. Button... -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/myBottomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" >
    </View>
</LinearLayout>
```

Using a `LinearLayout` works fines as long as the `ListView` contains only a few items and the total height of the dialog is not larger than the screen size. In this case the dialog automatically wraps its content and is only as height as it needs to be be.

However, when the `ListView` contains a large number of items and the size exceeds the screensize, the dialog is automatically adjusted to its max height and the bottom view is not visible anymore.

This can be solved by using a `RelativeLayout` as root instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/myBottomView" >
    </ListView>

    <!-- Any kind of view. e.g. Button... -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/myBottomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"            
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    </View>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This solves the problem described before: The bottom view is always visible at the bottom, no matter how hight the `ListView` is. However, now the dialog always occupies its max. height and is not adjusted to the actual height of the `ListView`?

**So each layouts solve one part of the problem but not both. How do I get both automatic sizing and bottom layout at the bottom at the same time?**

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Can you show some pictures of what you want and what you already got?

Comment: Can you just put `android:layout_weight="1"` for  ListView of the 1st one?.

Comment: Thanks @sunli_sunny, sometimes it's just too easy... This solved the problem!

Comment: ok I will make it an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need `android:layout_weight="1"` for ListView .
So your layout should look something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_weight="1"            <!-- this will force listview to expand according to it's height.. -->
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/myBottomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" >
    </View>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is work.but if parent <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout then not work.have you another solution

Comment: @bhoomika Post as a separate question with the xml. Let me have a look.